# How to create a textevariable Label (ttk) with Python

Tags: python, label, ttk

I'm trying to create a `Label` with `ttk`.

I aim to create a widget where the points of a word would appear.
I created an entry, and I'd like to display the points that the word is worth.

Here is my code:

This is the function creating the `Label`:

```
def create_variabletext_label2(root, col, row, val):
    val1 = IntVar()
    val1.set(m.comptabilisation_points(val.get()))

    # Here val is the value of the word input onto the entry widget
    # and m.comptabilisation_point() is a function that counts the
    # points of the word.
    label = Label(root, textvariable=val1)
    label.grid(column=col, row=row)
    return val1, label
```

Here is the function creating the entry:

```
def create_entry_string(root, width, col, row, columnspan, rowspan):
    val=StringVar()
    entry=ttk.Entry(root, width=width, textvariable=val)
    entry.grid(column=col, row=row, columnspan=columnspan, rowspan=rowspan)
    return val, entry
```

Then I call these functions:

```
val_entry_mot, entry_mot = create_entry_string(root, 15, 1, 1, 1, 1)
val_points, label_points = create_variabletext_label2(root, 1, 2, val_entry_mot)
```

My problem is that the `Label` keeps displaying `0`.
The label doesn't change according the word's points.

Thank's for your help.
MFF

Sorry for being vague.

Additional informations :

I'm trying to create a Scrabble game. Actually, my problem is that I don't know how to display the points that the word worth. Even if the entry's value change, the label doesn't change.

At first I thought the value of `val_entry_mot` wasn't changing. So I tried to display only the word that is input by changing the function `create_variable_text2()` by this one:

```
def create_variabletext_label2(root, col, row, val):
        label = Label(root, textvariable=val)
        label.grid(column=col, row=row)
        return val, label
```

It worked. Every time I changed the word in the Entry, the label was displaying the word.

Then, I thought the code that is supposed to count the word's point was defective. Here it is:

```
def comptabilisation_points(word):
    dico_values=values_scrabble()
    points=0
    for i in word.upper():
        points+=dico_values[i]
    return points
```

`values_scrabble()` is a function that opens a file and convert it into a dictionary = `{'A': 1, 'C': 3, 'B': 3, 'E': 1, 'D': 2, 'G': 2, 'F': 4, 'I': 1, 'H': 4, 'K': 10, 'J': 8, 'M': 2, 'L': 1, 'O': 1, 'N': 1, 'Q': 8, 'P': 3, 'S': 1, 'R': 1, 'U': 1, 'T': 1, 'W': 10, 'V': 4, 'Y': 10, 'X': 10, 'Z': 10}`

And it actually worked when I tried to count a word's points. So I suppose that my problem isn't here.

Here is a screen-shot of the game. It is in french but what you have to know is that the first `Entry` on the top is where you input the word and straight below is supposed to be displayed the word's points.

[image: Game screen shot]

I hope I've been clear. Thank you.

MFF

Comment: What is `m.comptabilisation_points(val.get())` supposed to do?

Comment: Well, it counts the word's points according to a dictionary, e.g : {'A':1,'E':2,'K':10,...}

Comment: Anyway, as `val.get()` just returns an emtpy string (because it is initialised to the empty string), you cannot expect meaningful output for `val1.set()`.

Answer (score 0):

`val_entry_mot` is not set and returns `''` which explains your issue:

```
In [1]: val_entry_mot.get()
Out[1]: ''
```

Hence, `val1.set()` cannot function properly.

If you set it to some value directly, your code would work, e.g.:

```
val1.set(123) # This properly renders "123" as Label text
```

Comment: Why is `val_entry_mot` not set ? Well, at first it is empty but when I input a word, the `val_entry_mot` 's value should change ? Isn't it ? Then the fonction `m.comptabilisation_point()` is supposed to return an integer...

Comment: You will have to check that -- given the minimal amount of code you provide I cannot tell you; but this seems to be the root cause of your problem...

Comment: Mmmh, sorry, I'm going to edit my question :s and provide the entire code.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm bothering you, but could you take a look one more time, please ? I'm facing this since this morning and I really don't know how to fix it :s. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'll have a look later tonight.